# Savage Worlds: Safety Harnesses and Airbags?

Tags: savage-worlds

So I just got Savage Worlds (Deluxe Edition) last night, and in true form, I started a cover-to-cover read, basically just hitting everything on the way through. It's all been pretty clear throughout, but I can't figure out one thing:

In the vehicle section for collisions, Safety Harnesses are brought up as halving damage from collisions, and airbags are included as saying "Do the same for air bags, but subtract one 
additional die of damage as well." Does this assume that safety harnesses and airbags are always used together? If so, are there any rules for a character who is unsecured but in a vehicle with airbags? Do you just reduce the single die? Or do the airbags alone provide the full effects of a safety harness plus the -1 die of damage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Both Harnesses and Airbags come into play.**

[According to Clint](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=300340&sid=7cda766546d642031221cc8f4408f968) who's a site admin on the forums for Pinnacle Entertainment Group/Great White Games (Publisher of Savage Worlds):

> Well, it would work as the example listed, with 2 vehicles with 2 passengers each, 6 damage rolls would made, one for each participant.
>
> To be specific (and as varied as possible), let's say a Semi hits an SUV at a relative speed of 35" for 7d6 damage, each vehicle has a driver and one passenger. The passenger is both cases is wearing a seat belt and the driver is not. The SUV also has air bags where the Semi does not.
>
> The Semi takes 7d6 damage applied against its Toughness.
>
> The SUV takes 7d6 damage applied against its Toughness.
>
> The driver of the Semi (no seat belt/no air bag) takes 7d6 damage applied against his Toughness (+4 for the Semi's Armor).
>
> The passenger of the Semi (seat belt/no air bag) takes 3d6 damage applied against his Toughness (+4 for the Semi's Armor).
>
> The driver of the SUV (no seat belt/air bag) takes 2d6 damage applied against his Toughness (+3 for the SUV's Armor).
>
> The passenger of the SUV (seat belt & air bag) takes 1d6 damage applied against his Toughness (+3 for the SUV's Armor).
>
> Each of those damage rolls is made individually, even the ones with the same number of dice.
>
> ---
>
> Clint Black
>   Savage Worlds Core Rules Brand Manager

Seeing as the passenger wearing his seat-belt and being added by an airbag takes less damage than the driver with just an airbag.

Comment: So it's cumulative, then.

Comment: That is how I am reading it. Specifically, it looks like he did airbags then harness, but He didn't actually show the math, just the results.

Comment: Yeah, it actually seems to have some issues with order of operations and rounding, but if you assume airbags then harness it looks okay.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I assumed Half rounded down w/ airbags first as its the only Order of Operations that allows you to reach the 1d6. 7d6/2 round down =3d6 -1d6 (airbags) =2d6. 2d6 / 2 (seatbelts) = 1d6

Comment: Yep, that's what it looks like.

Comment: Also, for your information, I see nothing wrong with this answer-I'm just seeing if anyone has any RAW stuff or if this is as good as it gets; which is the only reason why I haven't accepted it yet.

Comment: Clint answers are usually accepted as RAW. He is the Pinnacle official Q/A guy.

Comment: @KyleWilley Always good to wait for more answers before choosing a best answer.

JavierRivera thanks for the tip about Clint.

Comment: He answered a while back ago, and since his answer's pretty authoritative I figured it'd probably be a good bet to accept it.